# How to use spring rest template with SSL enabled domain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2

I have a java web application hosted on aws [ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) linux instance. I bought a domain from amazon's [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) service and enabled the SSL from [ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/).
I am able to access the application using domain name e.g https://www.example.com.

The problem comes when inside the application there is an API call using Spring Rest Template. Getting the following error.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
I/O error on GET request for **"https://www.example.com/portal-war/api/get/something/id22222"**: 
Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

If I access the same api **https://www.example.com/portal-war/api/get/something/id22222** outside the application (e.g. in browser or postman) , its working perfectly.

Please help me out to fix this issue!

Comment: do you have internet access from your ec2 instance?

Comment: yes its there..

Comment: well - you're getting a connection refused... if you curl the same endpoint from your instance - what response do you get then?

Comment: I am accessing the ec2 instance from windows pc using putty. If I ping my domain e.g. www.example.com from windows command line,  getting Request time out. Suspecting something wrong with rest template because where ever I have used rest template its throwing the error. Otherwise I am able to access the other parts of the application using browser.

Comment: when you ssh to your ec2 instance using putty - can you access any resource on the internet? i.e `ping google.com`

Comment: Yes I am able to ping..

Comment: from your local machine or your ec2 instance?

Comment: from my local machine

Comment: can you ping from your ec2 instance?

Comment: So I connected to ec2 through putty and typed there ping xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx (This ip got by typing what is my ip on google)
Got the following result      19 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17999ms

Comment: `ping google.com`? Looks like you need to grant internet access to your ec2 instance... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: Ping google.com is working fine. Got the reply ..... 64 bytes from xxx-in-f14.xx100.net (xxx.xxx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=11 ttl=44 time=16.8 ms

Comment: ok...what endpoint are you trying to connect to that isn't working?

Comment: Just an update in code if I am calling the api with https it giving error There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
I/O error on GET request for......... connection refused. But it I call api with http its working fine.